# Realm Query to count number of unique entries

Tags: swift, uitableview, realm, datasource

I have a data array of information, loaded from Realm, including names.

I would like to count the total number of unique name entries to produce a numerical value.

This numerical value will be used to display the unique names in a table view, one row per each unique name in numberOfRowsInSection.

Currently it will query and display the following on the TableView, which is all of the entries from the `myTableViewData`;

- Adam
- Adam
- Ben
- Ben
- Ben
- Charlie
- Darren
- Darren

I would like it to display only the entries that are unique, disregarding any duplicate names, as:

- Adam
- Ben
- Charlie
- Darren

```
var myTableViewData: Results<RecordOfInformation>? = nil
let Realm = try! Realm() 

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
        myTableViewData = realm.objects(RecordOfInformation.self).sorted(byKeyPath: "itemName")
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
             
        
        return myTableViewData!.count
    }
```

**EDIT**

I have amended myTableViewData to,

```
realm.objects(RecordOfInformation.self).distinct(by: ["itemName"]).sorted(byKeyPath: "itemName")
        tableView.reloadData()
```

The tableView will now display

- Adam
- Ben
- Charlie
- Darren

However, the output console, during `print("myTableViewData")`, will print all the information associated with each realm entry for each of the selected individual, unique names.

Is this too cumbersome on the efficiency to load all information, or is there a way to only load the itemName as an array to display only `itemName`, to appear as an array as "Adam, Ben, Charlie, Darren" in the console?

Comment: you can use [distinct method](https://realm.io/docs/swift/3.13.0/api/Classes/Results/distinct(by:).html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At a high level, if you have an array of Strings as shown in your question, and you want to get only unique Strings (no duplicates) you can cast it to a Set and you're done.

```
let nameArray = ["Adam", "Adam", "Ben", "Ben", "Ben", "Charlie", "Darren", "Darren"]
let nameSet = Set(nameArray)
print(nameSet)
```

and the output is

```
["Darren", "Charlie", "Ben", "Adam"]
```

If you would then like it ordered to be used as a dataSource, it can be cast back to an Array and sorted

```
let uniqueNameArray = Array(nameSet)
let orderedUniqueNameArray = uniqueNameArray.sorted()
print(orderedUniqueNameArray)
```

and the output

```
["Adam", "Ben", "Charlie", "Darren"]
```

(there are a lot of shortcuts that could be taken and you could probably make it a one-liner but I left it verbose for clarity)

EDIT

If you want to get Realm objects that are unique based on a certain property, you can use the .distinct function. Assume the Realm PersonClass as a `name` property

```
let people = realm.objects(PersonClass.self)
let uniquePeopleByName = people.distinct(by: ["name"])
```

Comment: Thank you, Jay. I attempted your method, and ran into all kinds of errors. I do not think I explained my question clearly. I do not have an array of simple strings as interpreted. I am pulling the itemName string from the entire realm. I would like to only pull the itemName strings from the realm, not the additional information associated with each entry.

Comment: @Gun24SGR See the edit to my answer if you want to work with the realm objects and not strings.